# Discount on whole category if product from different category in cart

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, discount

I got a bike category and a bike-related-products category.

If customer adds a bike to the cart there should be a global discount on bike-related-products category like 10%.

To make it clear: I only need the discount appear in cart - not in listing itself after adding a bike.

Can this be done with shopping cart rules?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, sure.  Set condition (second tab) to has products from category Bikes  and then set actions (third tab) to apply 10% discount on bike-related products.